# Free RDP server for Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm not really a Windows user but I have a virtual machine with Windows 8. I have no Pro edition, so Remote Desktop does not work.

Is there a free version of an RDP server that I could install? VNC is no option since it is really slow.

Other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: clients galore, but no, no servers. you will have to go with something more alien, like VNC or TeamViewer or Go-to-PC.

Comment: Just a nit, RDP is the "Remote Desktop Protocol", which is something owned by Microsoft, if you want to use any remote desktop software (and not restrict yourself to one that uses RDP) you really open up your options.

Comment: With most servers/clients being suggested, you may not connect in "control" mode, so make sure you check that out before you commit to one.  What this means, you connect in "spectator" and require a physical mouse-click to take control of the machine.

Comment: Consider installing RDPWrap to bypass the restriction. https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/releases

Answer (score 2):

In the "other suggestions" category, try *VirtualBox*, it has [native RDP support](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) for anything running in a VM. Though vbox proper is free, RDP support is an extension, and falls under the *personal, educational or evaluation use only* licence.

If you use vmware, you have the option of the *VI client*, though its console support lacks something (frankly, I wouldn't wish it on anyone...)

I use VNC (Xorg module) tunnelled over ssh, on medium bandwidth links, asymmetric links, and medium latency links, it works fine strictly for management, not heavy interactive use.

If you have a X GUI client you use to display your VM instances then you may be able to reverse forward that from the remote machine to your local display (e.g. `ssh -XY`, or manually with `ssh -R` and setting `DISPLAY`).

The only other free software I have used is [xrdp](http://software.opensuse.org/package/xrdp?search_term=xrdp) (I have successfully, though not heavily, used this version: https://github.com/zeha/xrdp-suse-fork ). It might be a little fiddly to configure, but it certainly works, I can connect to my Linux desktop using a standard `mstsc`. There are two caveats:

- it actually uses *Xvnc*, but only as an X server for your session, there's no vnc "on the wire"
- it's a distinct X server, so it's not your desktop X server instance

Unused by me, but might be worth a look in the future: [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) recently added *experimental* server support. Based on the size of the window drawn before the server segfaults it's not a standalone X server, it interacts with the running X server. It doesn't seem ready for production use right now though ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if he went Virtualbox or VMware to just go with installing another OS?  Personally I feel if he went that route he is half way setup for it.

Comment: VirtualBox is no option because I'm using KVM

Comment: Updated with a few more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)?

They have versions for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I manage my IT department and use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com).

Free version allows you to add as many computers as you want, with limited features besides remote control.

The Pro (paid) version offers you a ton of [features](https://secure.logmein.com/products/pro/features.aspx) such as running batch processes remotely, inventory management and remote-to-local printing. I recommend it!